# IN postgressql "pgstartup.log" occupied 350 GB space in disk

Tags: postgresql-9.2

How  to reduce the pgstartup.log file size.
If i delete pgstartup.log what will happen.
We are using postgresql in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server.

Comment: That is probably not a file generated by PostgreSQL. You do not say what OS you are on, nor how you run PostgreSQL. Did you look at its content? Also PostgreSQL 9.2 is quite old now, you should think about upgrading as it is not supported anymore and will not have security updates (and PostgreSQL just got hit by a CVE)

Comment: It looks like you may have two accounts. See [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to get them merged, so you can edit the question yourself.